# Powershell make function from working code

Tags: function, powershell

Need your advise, how to re-arrange part of the script into function to call it within script, to assemble new credentials.

Here is a script:

```
$vault="3.3.3.3:8500"   
#  Check Vault login for Tech profile
#  Input Login & password
$pair = (Get-Credential)
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$Headers = @{Authorization = $basicAuthValue}
$rawcontent=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vault -Headers $Headers).StatusCode
```

Can anyone give me an example, how to assemble this part of code into function, to call it into if/elseif section in case of wrong entered credentials?

```
if ( $rawcontent -contains '200' ) { Write-Host "Technician is authenticated!" }
[ elseif ( $rawcontent -contains '400' ) {Write-Host "Bad credentials!" | # call Ask-Creds function to re-enter creds } ]
[ elseif ( $rawcontent -contains '000' ) {Write-Host "Connection failed!" | Exit 1 } ]
```

UPD1 - the code above is working. I've tried to assemble some function, based on code above, but it's not returning any value to $rawcontent variable. Can anyone give me a hint, what I'm doint wrong:

```
function Ask-Creds {
    param(
        $Credential = (Get-credential -message 'Please enter  Technician`s login & password for Terminal registration:')        
    )
    $vault="3.3.3.3:8500" 
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Credential))
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds" 
    $Headers = @{Authorization = $basicAuthValue}
    $rawcontent=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vault -Headers $Headers).StatusCode
}

Ask-Creds

echo $rawcontent #returns nothing
```

Comment: `$rawcontent` is a local variable inside the `Ask-Creds` functions, so is not visible outside the function.  If the last line of your function is simply `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vault -Headers $Headers).StatusCode`, then it will return the value to the caller, which will, by default, be shown on screen, though you could capture it into a variable for later use, if you like: `$result = Ask-Cred`

Comment: @boxdog thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @boxdog answer, I was able to assemble corrected function:

```
function Ask-Creds {
    param(
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        $Credential = (Get-credential -message 'Please enter  Technician`s login & password for Terminal registration:')        
    )
    $vault="3.3.3.3:8500" 
    $encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Credential))   
    $basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds" 
    $Headers = @{Authorization = $basicAuthValue}
    $rawcontent=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vault -Headers $Headers).StatusCode
    echo "$rawcontent"
}

Ask-Creds
```